# How to find memory leaks in an app written in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, memory-leaks

I have a big application written in ReactJS and wants to find out the memory leaks happening in my code. Is there any tool or technique to find the same?

Regards,
SJ

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use google chrome's developers tools `Profiling memory performance`,
by taking snapshots, `Take Heap Snapshot` and do Comparison.
basically take a snapshot before action, then after action and you can check the "Comparison" view to see if anything was detected.